# How many different values of weight of edges can I fit into this maximally?

Tags: combinatorics, graph-theory

Suppose I have $n$ vertices and the graph is complete. Now each edge is assigned with a weight. The requirement is that any triangle that can be found in the graph must have at least 2 sides having the same weight (similar to an isosceles triangle but the triangular inequality is not required.) The best situation would be that all edges have the same weight, but how many different values of edges can I fit into this graph maximally?

I am thinking about using some combinatorics like n choose 3. But it doesn't seem to work on the small examples that I tried on my own. Can someone help me out?

Comment: What are your results for small values of $n$?

Comment: @CalvinLin I got something very close to n like 4 numbers for 5 vertices with 10 edges. But I am not sure if it's maximal or how this will work in larger set. I was expecting some fraction, some root, or exponential to come into play but I don't know how to get one.

Comment: I suspect the answer is $n-1$. There is a simple construction. However, I'm not certain how to prove it.

Answer (score 2):

We claim that the answer is $n-1$. Suppose instead that $G$ is a graph that satisfies the property but has greater than $n-1$ distinct weights.
Without loss of generality, assume that the vertex set of the graph is $[n]=\{1,2,\ldots,n\}$. For $1\leq k\leq n$, denote by $G_k$ the induced subgraph of $G$ on the vertex set $[k]$.

Let $k_0$ be the minimum $k$ such that $G_k$ has greater than $k-1$ distinct weights. $G_{k_0-1}$ has at most $k_0-2$ distinct weights. This implies that the vertex $k_0$ has (at least) two edges in $G_{k_0}$ incident on it with distinct weights that do not appear in $G_{k_0-1}$. However, in this case, the triangle formed by (the vertices corresponding to) these two edges has $3$ distinct weights!
This is a contradiction, and therefore, the answer is at most $n-1$.

This bound is also attained for the graph where an edge from $i$ to $j$ ($1\leq i<j\leq n$), is labelled $i$.

Comment: +1 Very nice. Note that you could have done the induction directly, in a similar manner. IE Consider $G_{n+1}$. We know that $ G_{n}$ has $n-1$ distinct weights. If edges emitting from $v_{n+1}$ introduce $\geq 2 $ distinct weights, then we get our scalene triangle.